# Is there a way to save a tracker's tracking data and restore it after deletion

Tags: python, scripting, movie-clip-editor

I'm currently developing a Python script for Blender that automates the cleanup function to progressively reduce the solve error in tracking. The script successfully decreases the solve error over iterations; however, occasionally, an unexpected spike in solve error occurs.

Here's an illustrative sequence of the solve error progression:

**5.0**

**4.5**

**4.3**

**4.0**

**3.7**

**2.5**

**1.4**

**89.9 (Unexpected spike)**

At the eighth step, the solve error suddenly jumps from 1.4 to 89.9. I believe this is due to the deletion of specific trackers during the cleanup process, which adversely affects the solve error.

I'm seeking a way to restore the recently deleted trackers whenever such an error spike occurs, aiming to revert the solve error back to its previous lower value (in this case, 1.4). I am thinking it may be possible to save the trackers before deletation but I am not to sure.

Does anyone have suggestions or insights into how this might be accomplished? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a programmer but in such an instance can you not program in a conditional if statement that if such a tracker were to be found, do an undo operation, else move onto the next tracker.

Comment: I have tried using the undo function but with no success… I have used the push method for undo but I can’t get it to work.

Comment: Usually when working with data sets in programming you can write the data into an array/table which then can be referenced and edited accordingly, I'd assume such a thing is possible for this case.